# Conditional average or replace value if zero in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a problem finding the right code for the following problem.

Here is a simplified and short version of my dataframe df :

```
Line  Id   Amount
1      1    10
2      2    12
3      2    13
4      2    0
5      3    11
6      4    12
7      4    14
8      5    0
9      6    11
10     6    0
```

I would like to create another colum Amount_Avrg with the folowing conditions:

-if several lines have the same Id and an Amount that is different from zero the case for lines 2 and 3 and for lines 6 and 7, calculate the average of the different amounts

-if one line has an amount that is equal with 0 then:

A/ erase it if it is alone (if there is no other line with the same Id and a value different from 0) (the case of line 8)

B/ if there is one line with the same Id and a value different from 0 (the case for lines 9 and 10), replace 0 with the value of the other

C/ if there are two lines or more with a value different from zero (the case for lines 2 and 3), replace 0 with the average of the other amounts

The final dataframe I am expecting would then look like this one:

```
Line  Id   Amount  Amount_Avrg
1      1    10     10
2      2    12     12.5
3      2    13     12.5 
4      2    0      12.5
5      3    11     11
6      4    12     13
7      4    14     13
9      6    11     11
10     6    0      11
```

I have read in many answers that if loops were not efficient on R so if you could help me with another solution, that would be fantastic :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ave` to calculate the `mean` per `Id` and then subset with `!is.na` to remove the rows where you have only `0` per `Id`.

```
x$Amount_Avrg <-  ave(x$Amount, x$Id, FUN=function(x) mean(x[x>0]))
x  <- x[!is.na(x$Amount_Avrg),]
x
#   Line Id Amount Amount_Avrg
#1     1  1     10        10.0
#2     2  2     12        12.5
#3     3  2     13        12.5
#4     4  2      0        12.5
#5     5  3     11        11.0
#6     6  4     12        13.0
#7     7  4     14        13.0
#9     9  6     11        11.0
#10   10  6      0        11.0
```

Or with `within` and `na.omit`:

```
na.omit(within(x, mount_Avrg <- ave(Amount, Id, FUN=function(x) mean(x[x>0]))))
```

Or using `aggregate` and `merge`:

```
merge(x, aggregate(cbind(Amount_Avrg = Amount) ~ Id, data=x[x$Amount>0,], mean))
```

Data:

```
x  <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Line  Id   Amount
1      1    10
2      2    12
3      2    13
4      2    0
5      3    11
6      4    12
7      4    14
8      5    0
9      6    11
10     6    0")
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `ID` and take `mean` of non-zero `Amount` and remove rows with `NA` in them.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(mn = mean(Amount[Amount > 0])) %>%
  filter(!is.na(mn))

#   Line    Id Amount  mn
#  <int> <int>  <int> <dbl>
#1     1     1     10  10  
#2     2     2     12  12.5
#3     3     2     13  12.5
#4     4     2      0  12.5
#5     5     3     11  11  
#6     6     4     12  13  
#7     7     4     14  13  
#8     9     6     11  11  
#9    10     6      0  11
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, mn := mean(Amount[Amount > 0]), by = Id][!is.na(mn)]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Line = 1:10, Id = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 6L), Amount = c(10L, 12L, 13L, 0L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 0L, 
11L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: thanks Ronak! The data.table code works perfectly. For the dplyr code, does it save it as the new df dataframe or is there a way to save it as another dataframe (df2 for instance)?

Comment: @Xav64 `dplyr` code doesn't update by reference, you need to assign it to a new object `df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(mn = mean(Amount[Amount > 0])) %>%
  filter(!is.na(mn))`

Answer (score 2):

If you create a summary table of all the nonzero-means, you can right-join that to the original table to get the result displayed in the question.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

nonzero_means <- df[Amount > 0, .(Amount_Avg = mean(Amount)), Id]

df[nonzero_means, on = .(Id)]
#    Line Id Amount Amount_Avg
# 1:    1  1     10       10.0
# 2:    2  2     12       12.5
# 3:    3  2     13       12.5
# 4:    4  2      0       12.5
# 5:    5  3     11       11.0
# 6:    6  4     12       13.0
# 7:    7  4     14       13.0
# 8:    9  6     11       11.0
# 9:   10  6      0       11.0
```